# "No address associated with hostname" but minecraft client can enter it?

Tags: linux, networking, hostname

I apologize if this site is not for this kind of questions, but this is really puzzling and I have no idea what is happening.

I have 2 minecraft clients, tlauncher and Shiginima launcher. There is a server that I usually play, and I can enter it normally with Shiginima. However if I try to connect with tlauncher it says: `Unknown host` and doesn't connect. I can connect to other servers with tlauncher, just not that one. Furthermore I can ping those others that I can connect to. However if I try to ping the one that doesn't work, it says: `ping: <host_name_of_server>: No address associated with hostname`.

I have no idea what is happening, and can't find anything about how to solve it or why it happens on the internet..

(I am using linux btw)

Comment: Those error messages point to a DNS problem. Have you used a DNS tool such as `dig` or `host` or `nslookup` to see what responses your DNS servers are giving for the host/domain names for the two Minecraft servers in question? If I had to guess, I'd say the problematic server is only reachable via IPv6, and I'd guess that tlauncher doesn't support IPv6, but Shiginima does. On many Unix-like systems (possibly including your particular flavor of Linux), `ping` doesn't support IPv6 either; you must use `ping6` to ping hosts via IPv6.

Comment: @Spiff I am using arch-linux. Both `ping` and `ping -6` returned `No address associated with hostname`. Then I did `ping -4` and it worked. However when I tried `ping -4` again, it also returned `No address associated with hostname` , and doesn't work anymore.. I was able sometimes to enter the server with tlauncher before too.

Comment: And now I used another internet, and even shiginima launcher doesn't work (same message)...

Comment: I think you're having DNS problems. If you don't know how to diagnose them yourself using tools like `dig`, `nslookup`, or `host`, then consider editing your Question to provide the host/domain names of the two servers you're trying to connect to, so that someone else can do the DNS troubleshooting.